# How to remove HttpServletRequest parameters (in JSP)?

Tags: java, jsp

How can an `HttpServletRequest` parameter (especially in JSP) be unset or removed (like in PHP using the `unset($_POST['index'])` function)? I have tried the following.

```
Map requestMap=request.getParameterMap();
requestMap.remove("index");
```

but it says

> No modifications are allowed to a locked ParameterMap

Is there a way to unset request parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940418/best-way-to-remove-a-httpservletrequest-parameter-in-a-controller-class

Comment: I don't see the point, why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to unset request parameters?

AFAIK, not within the JSP itself (or any Servlet for that matter).

But you could write a Filter that wrapped the current Request in a way that replaces the parameter map.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is write a `HttpFilter`, write a `HttpRequestWrapper` of yours(`MyRequestWrapper`). Override the `getParameter` method of `HttpRequestWrapper` in your `MyRequestWrapper` such that you don't return parameters(may be always return null).

Within filter code, you should override the `doFilter` method and create a new `MyRequestWrapper` from `ServletRequest` Object, then do `chanin.doFilter(myRequestWrapper, response)`