# Modifying HttpServletRequest parameters with a Servlet Filter doesn't seem to work

Tags: jsp, servlets

I need to remove/modify some of `HttpServletRequest` parameters. I'm trying to do so by using a `Filter` based on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11304100/1391249) I posted a few days ago.

In the `Filter`, I'm trying to wrap the `HttpServletRequest` by inheriting the `HttpServletRequestWrapper` class as follows.

```
private final static class FilteredRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public FilteredRequest(ServletRequest request) {
        super((HttpServletRequest) request);
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String paramName) {
        return super.getParameter(paramName);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String paramName) {
        return super.getParameterValues(paramName);
    }

    @Override
    public Map getParameterMap() {
        Map<Object, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        Map originalParameterMap = super.getParameterMap();

        for (Object o : originalParameterMap.entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry<Object, Object> pairs = (Entry<Object, Object>) o;
            parameterMap.put(pairs.getKey(), pairs.getValue());
        }
        return parameterMap;  //Returning a modifiable ParameterMap.
    }
}
```

It's an inner class within the `Filter` class. In the `doFilter()` method,

```
chain.doFilter(new FilteredRequest(request), (HttpServletResponse)response);
```

the constructor of the above class is being invoked (that wraps the request).

---

Now, I expect any of request parameters to modify/unset in **my Spring MVC controller class**. I'm trying to remove the parameter in the controller class as follows.

```
Map requestMap=request.getParameterMap();
requestMap.remove("txt_country_name");
```

Alternatively,

```
requestMap.put("txt_country_name", null);
```

Accordingly, the request parameter `txt_country_name` should be removed from the `HttpServletRequest` but it isn't removed (nor it throws any exception like "*No modifications are allowed to a locked ParameterMap*"). What am I missing here? Am I following a wrong way?

By the way, *Making/using a request attribute all the time through out the entire application doesn't seem to be the best solution*.

[I need to remove/modify request parameter **within the Spring MVC controller class** and not within the `Filter` itself]

Comment: Must create a new request instance, set the values and then forward it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your remove method modifies the mutable map returned by `getParameterMap()`. But the next call to `getParameterMap()` reconstructs a new mutable map containing all the parameters of the wrapped query.

The mutable map should be constructed when the `FilteredRequest` is constructed, and it should be stored in an instance field.