# How to remove a parameter from HttpServletRequest request?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my web application I am sending two parameters: `action` and `productCode` from JSP to Servlet. Based on that action some processing will happen.

Now after action is performed I am forwarding control to a JSP. The problem is that when the new JSP is opened the URL still contains the name of Servlet and the Parameters. So in case if someone refreshes the page, the same action will be performed again and again.

If somehow I am able to remove the parameters from URL then I handled a no parameter situation in servlet.

Can anyone please tell me how can I remove the parameter from request object?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you send a redirect to another URL.

Comment: you cannot do this way... forwards are meant to preserve everything in the request... if you want to remove something from the request, you need to use redirect..

Comment: Please stop sending unwanted parameters in request, use filter to remove them before processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forward operation is transparent to the client and forwards the request on to another handler for processing. Perhaps a forward is not exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I think you are correct. I just found [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181) and I think I should use redirect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove a **parameter** from a `HttpServletRequest`. The very definition of a parameter is that it came from the client (browser).

Perhaps you mean a request **attribute** ?

For that you can use:

```
request.getAttribute(String name)
request.setAttribute(String name, Object o)
request.removeAttribute(String name)
```

Comment: actually I meant HttpServletRequest only.

Answer (score 1):

For the record (if someone does not find the other questions/answers):

1. [*The good practice is to wrap the request object in another object
   using a servlet filter. (...)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3940511/2039709)
2. [*Subclass HttpServletRequestWrapper and override the getParameter
   methods. (...)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190865/2039709)

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a parameter from a HttpServletRequest - but you can change its value by passing new values for this parameter.

For example, after login to hide a password value you can forward to next servlet/page this way:

```
"*/PAM_show_orders?orderDate=2020-04-16&**password=+++***".
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is set that parameter to null and check before performing any operation if that attribute is set to null. This way you still will be able to use request forwarding.

For example:

```
request.setAttribute("Your_attribute",null);
```

checking for not null while performing action can be done using

```
String para=request.getAttribute("Your_attribute");
if(para.equals(null)){
    //do this 
}
else{
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: This won't work. The .getAttribute("something")  will return null since you set is as  null and trying to use .equals() method from null would throw a NPE.

Answer (score -5):

When  your request handler is over you can just use:

```
response.setParameter("action") = "";
response.setParameter("productCode") = "";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no `setParameter()` method under `response`

Comment: That isn't even a legal Java code. There's no `setParameter()` and you can't assign value to method call.