# Add Extra parameter to HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there is any way to add parameter to request object in spring 4,

like

```
public Map<String,Object> myMethod(HttpServletRequest request){
      request.setParameter("myKey", "myValue"); // It dont have this kind of method
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `HttpServletRequest` is not a  `Spring` class. Why exactly do you need this?

Comment: We are using spring framwork for web application, its a HttpServletRequest servlet api class, i need to add some parameter in request object

Comment: Why do you need to add parameter to the request object? what are you doing with it?

Comment: this question might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190833/is-it-possible-to-add-to-the-available-parameters-of-a-request-httpservletreque

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HttpServletRequest`object cannot be changed.
But you can add additional attributes to it, using `HttpServletRequest.setAttribute()` method.
This is useful, when you forward the request to another page:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = httpServletRequest
    .getRequestDispatcher("/url/to/new/page");
dispatcher.forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
```

The receiving servlet then can read the additional attributes, you set.
It has to be in the same web application on the same server instance.